# How can I say "Good luck!" in Italian?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

There are many situations in which we would wish someone "Good luck!", for instance when someone is embarking in something difficult or dangerous. How can we express a similar thing in Italian?

Comment: Are you using the expression earnestly, as in "I really hope you succeed", or sarcastically, as in "Are you trying to empty that pool with a teaspoon? Good luck with that!"? For the former, the existing answers are good; for the latter, I'd use "Auguri!" instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The "neutral" way is the literal translation:

> **Buona fortuna!**

The more colloquial way (not rude or offensive, *can* generally be used with anyone, though it might depend on the situation) is an idiomatic expression:

> **In bocca al lupo!**

to which the person who is wished luck usually replies:

> **Crepi (il lupo)!**

Comment: the second is good especially when the other person is superstitious

Comment: Si potrebbe anche dire 'in culo alla balena', ma poi ... come si risponde?

Comment: @april: This is not something you just use with anyone. When in doubt, just avoid it.
 
Non avevo dubbi che qualcuno l'avrebbe menzionato. Che io sappia la risposta è "speriamo che non caghi".

Comment: Just to clarify, «*In bocca al lupo!*» is a rough equivalent of «Break a leg!»

Comment: @laika I disagree. It is used almost everywhere and with anyone, why do you say that?

Comment: @Ant For example, before exams superstitious people don't want to hear "buona fortuna" or "auguri", because it would bring bad luck. For "scaramanzia" you can say to them only "in bocca al lupo". Then of course not so many people are really superstitious, so they wouldn't care for either of the wishes

Comment: @laika uhm, I see your point :)

Comment: I don't think "In bocca al lupo!" is colloquial. It's just used in a context where you care about the other person.

Comment: A remark here: You can safely answer back to 'In bocca al lupo!' with a simple 'Grazie'. I prefer this way because I don't want the wolf to die. In fact 'Crepi (il lupo)' means 'let the wolf die'. Many Italians don't know but we say 'in bocca al lupo' because the female wolf carries in her mouth her puppies, so she helps and protects them, just as the fortune does. You don't really want to kill those who protect you.

Answer (score 9):

"Buona fortuna" is the literal translation of "Good luck".
If you're in an informal context (eg talking to friends), you may want to use "In bocca al lupo" (literally: [go] into the wolf's mouth) instead.

Answer (score 4):

I'll depart from the obvious answers, and suggest you to say: "**Auguri!**".

This is the most neutral greeting in most cases: no particular register, doesn't assume a good or bad occasion, doesn't invoke the *sorte* etc. Can sometimes be sarcastic; but if you are sincere it won't, just like "Good luck".

I'm pointing this alternative out because it happens to me almost daily that I think "Auguri!" for someone who only speaks English, but I'm prevented from saying it because in English any translation may be ambiguous.