# Is there an equivalent word or phrase for "May it be easy" or "Good Luck"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

I always want to say the phrase like "Good luck" or "More power to you" when I'm leaving from some workplace where there are some workers who are still working or when I'm leaving but my friends still are studying. I'm searching -  maybe it's because of my country of origin.

Because in Turkish we say "Kolay gelsin" which can be translated into English as "May it be easy" and I've never found this kind of phrase in any Latin languages.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Mertcan!

Comment: Related question (maybe a duplicate?): http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3838.

Comment: Half a question is a duplicate but the other half isn't because of that "more power to you" bit. Which could be like saying "good for you" (buon per te). I don't even think it has the same intent of "good luck" since its a bit like saying "well done, you did it!" (you are going at home and we are still here). For the turkish expression we have "che Dio ce la mandi buona" ma non so quanto possa essere diffusa una versione con "TE la mandi"

Comment: Grazie per buona risposta @Erik vanDoren :)

Comment: Ojalá would be the equivalent for me in Spanish

Comment: @DavidCabrera: Please use the "Your Answer" box to write a real answer to the OP question. Anyway, I don't agree that this is an equivalent in Spanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments *Good luck* is usually said *Buona fortuna!* or *In bocca al lupo!* (the latter similar to the English *Break a leg!*). However in the context of the question, if I'm leaving when people are still working I'd say

> Buon lavoro!

(lit. *Have a good work!*) or

> Buono studio!

In the case of people studying.

Comment: _More power to you_ sounds a stronger way of saying. I am not sure there a similar way of saying in Italian.

Comment: @mario I agree. This translation is based on the context given in the OP and the Turkish sentence it wanted to emulate (*May it be easy*). I've never heard *More power to you* used in such circumstances.